# Does node js support cross domain requests?

Tags: node.js

I have called cross domain URL from http method in node js. But i am getting error called "getaddressinfo not found".

My code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    path: '/index.html'
};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
 console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
 console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

 // Buffer the body entirely for processing as a whole.
 var bodyChunks = [];
 res.on('data', function(chunk) {
   // You can process streamed parts here...
   bodyChunks.push(chunk);
 }).on('end', function() {
   var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
   console.log('BODY: ' + body);
   // ...and/or process the entire body here.
 })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
 console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code here or in jsFiddle/jsBin

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a cross domain request from the POV of node really. Cross domain requests are something the browser does to prevent a webpage from being bad. Servers have no such restrictions.

Your example works for me

```
> node yourexample.js

STATUS: 302
HEADERS: {"cache-control":"private","content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","location":"http://www.google.co.jp/index.html?gfe_rd=cr&ei=IXZQVbCGOcWT8Qeg1IH4DQ","content-length":"271","date":"Mon, 11 May 2015 09:28:01 GMT","server":"GFE/2.0","alternate-protocol":"80:quic,p=1","connection":"close"}
BODY: <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.jp/index.html?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=IXZQVbCGOcWT8Qeg1IH4DQ">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
STATUS: 302
HEADERS: {"cache-control":"private","content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","location":"http://www.google.co.jp/index.html?gfe_rd=cr&ei=IXZQVbCGOcWT8Qeg1IH4DQ","content-length":"271","date":"Mon, 11 May 2015 09:28:01 GMT","server":"GFE/2.0","alternate-protocol":"80:quic,p=1","connection":"close"}
BODY: <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.jp/index.html?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=IXZQVbCGOcWT8Qeg1IH4DQ">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

If I change `www.google.com` to `somenonsensedomainname` then I get

```
ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND somenonsensedomainname
```

Which suggests your network does not have DNS setup correctly or is otherwise having DNS issues.